# How to use Nuxt 3 api middleware just for one endpoint?

Tags: nuxt.js, yup, nuxtjs3

code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jegnhv?file=server/api/users/index.post.js

I want to use `validateUserSchema` as middleware only for endpoint `/api/users` with POST method.

Comment: Make a conditional regarding the path used and run the middleware only there.

Comment: Yeah it can work but I want to use something like Express middleware because I able to use a lot of validation middlewares and I don't need to run all of them. And also I looking for simple way reuse validators on some endpoints.

Best what I can do now is write my own EventHandler with handler decorators. But it looks like I'm trying to make something that should already exist

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found what I wanted, so this is my solution with decorator:

```
import { BaseSchema } from "yup";
import { sendError, H3Error, CompatibilityEvent } from "h3";

const validateBody = (schema: BaseSchema) => {
  return (
    _target: any,
    _propertyName: string,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => void>
  ) => {
    const method = descriptor.value!;
    descriptor.value = async function (...args) {
      try {
        const body = await useBody(args[0].req);
        if (!body) {
          throw new H3Error("No body found");
        }
        await schema.validate(body);
      } catch (error) {
        sendError(
          args[0],
          new H3Error("Validation error")
        );
      }
      return method.apply(this, args);
    };
  };
};

class CreateUser {
  @validateBody(userSchema)
  static async handler(event: CompatibilityEvent) {
    return await useBody(event.req);
  }
}

export default defineEventHandler(CreateUser.handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can make it a server middleware by putting it in server/middleware/users.post.ts(js) file.
There you can extend your request context by edidting e.context.your_name
Finally, you can return an error inside your handler in server/api/user.post.ts(js) and handle it on the client.
Remember that in order to achieve both good security and UX you need to make both server  and client-side form validation. On the client you can use :invalid css selector or pattern attribute. [check out the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)